# Create unit test to check if any class uses any method from specific class/namespace

Tags: c#, unit-testing

For a C# assembly project, I want to create a unit test that detects if code from a specific namespace is used. E.g. If any method from the namespace `System.Linq` is used, the unit test should fail.

Can this be accomplished?

Comment: This looks more like static code analysis than a unit test.

Comment: Can you remove the using System.Linq? In this way the project will not compiled.

Comment: @AzzyElvul unless they use the fully qualified method names in the code, avoiding having a `using` statement for importing the namespace.

Comment: @gunr2171 you can call method through reflection, so static analysis may not help. l33t I don't know a simple way to achive this, but you can solve it with c++ by implementing [ICorProfilerCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/icorprofilercallback-interface)

Comment: @AleksAndreev exactly, there is a number of ways to obfuscate your code.

Comment: @gunr2171, it can certainly be done using some kind of static code analysis. Given the tools I have, it would be better if it could be done using a regular unit test, e.g. through reflection.

Comment: that's not a unit test, that's a code standard, make it part of your process that no one can use system.linq, if your team agrees and move on with your life. why the need to police that?